# libicuuc: DSO missing from command line

Tags: gcc, linker, g++, linker-errors

I run the following linker command

```
g++ -Wl,-rpath,/opt/Qt/5.11.1/gcc_64/lib -o qt_mapnik main.o mainwindow.o moc_mainwindow.o   -L/usr/local/lib -lmapnik -lboost_filesystem -lboost_regex -lpng -lproj -ltiff -licui18n -lboost_system -lharfbuzz -ljpeg -licuuc -lfreetype -lz -ldl -L/home/mark/Documents/mapnik/freetype -L/usr/lib -pthread -L/opt/Qt/5.11.1/gcc_64/lib -lQt5Widgets -lQt5Gui -lQt5Core -lGL -lpthread
```

It errors with this message

```
/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-ld: main.o: undefined reference to symbol '_ZNK6icu_6013UnicodeString10doHashCodeEv'
//usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libicuuc.so.60: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
```

It is telling me that the libicuuc library is missing from the linker command (i.e. `-licuuc`), but it is definitely there. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that libicuuc also exists in to places on my computer. The compiler was finding it first in `/opt/Qt/5.11.1/gcc_64/lib/libicuuc.so.56`. However, the version that it needed was in `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libicuuc.so.60` The linker command can be changed by replacing `-licuuc` with `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libicuuc.so.60`